# "Unable to connect to server: connection failed: FATAL: password authentication failed" on brandly installed postgres and PGAdmin4

Tags: server, connection, postgresql, database, pgadmin

I want to create a new server and a new postgres database from the PGAdmin4 UI just-installed on Ubuntu 22.04

I already did this before but I don't remember how did I do id.

The server I created last time had these credentials:

```
name
postgres-local

username
postgres

pw
postgres

hostanme / address
127.0.0.1

port
5432

server group
Servers
```

I want to keep these credentials because I have this database to be used by some legacy application.

So I installed postgresql and then PGAdmin4 on Ubuntu by doing

## postgres

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib -y
```

## PGAdmin4

By following [this article](https://linux.how2shout.com/install-postgresql-pgadmin-4-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-linux/), I have run

```
curl  -fsSL https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/pgadmin.gpg

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list'

cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list

sudo apt update
sudo apt install pgadmin4

systemctl status apache2

sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh

sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https
```

Now I open PGAdmin4 on

http://localhost/pgadmin4/browser/

and there is no server available. So I tried to add one, with the configurations written upwards.

but as I try to save the configurations and create the db, this message pops up

```
Unable to connect to server: connection failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" connection server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres".
```

what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by launching these commands in my Ubuntu terminal

```
# become the postgres user
sudo -i -u postgres

# open the postgres shell
psql

# create a void database with the name I want
create database "postgres-local";

# give privileges to the already-existing user postgres to access that database
grant all privileges on database "postgres-local" to postgres;

# set the password 'postgres' to user  'postgres'
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres';
```